# process only the top n rows of a gzipped file in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I need to extract some string values out of a text file from the top n rows (around 50 rows).  In some cases the files are gzipped and in some cases they are not.

currently, I'm using the following to read the file, but this reads the entire file and is slow to process very large files.

```
set f [open "| zcat -f $filename" r]
```

if the file is not gzipped, then this seems to work OK and seems pretty fast.

```
set f [open "| head -n 50 $filename" r]
```

but when it is gzipped, I can't seem to zcat just the top n rows.  I've tried this but I get an error at the tclsh

```
set f [open "| zcat -f $filename | head -n 50" r]
set data [read $f]
close $f

%child killed: write on pipe with no readers
```

I can just try to catch the error and move on since it does seem to push the data into the $data variable, but I'm wondering if I'm doing something illegal here.

Alternatively, is there a pure Tcl way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes out of `close` and is because `zcat` was stopped (by a signal, `SIGPIPE`) before it had written all the lines out. It's expected, and you can safely `catch` it and ignore it. Put the `catch` around the `close`.

---

In Tcl 8.6 (but not any previous version, nor in the free-standing zlib package for Tcl; this was functionality we added when we imported the package into Tcl), you can do this in pure Tcl.

```
set f [open $filename]
zlib push gunzip $f

# Read those lines! This oneliner is a hack!
set lines [lmap - [lrepeat 50 -] {gets $f}]

# NB: We don't need to put a catch around this now
close $f
```

The `zlib` command provides compression and decompression; `zlib push` is used to add in compression or decompression to a channel, such as in this case where the `gunzip` channel filter has been applied.

Comment: Thanks, you are a wealth of Tcl knowledge.  This is incredibly fast.  It actually works faster than the head command.  I guess the only thing here is that I have to check if the file is gzipped or not before running the zlib push command, but I guess that's relatively easy.  It would be nice if there were something like zcat -f which works on either gzipped or ungzipped files, but that's minor.  thanks!

Comment: as a followup to this, it looks like while using catch{} to catch the error from using zcat | head works functionally within Tcl to generate the correct results, it apparently leaves zombie processes open on the server and in my case, saturated the available process handles which caused other processes to error out due to inability to create new processes.  So lessen learned, don't take shortcuts and do things the right way.  Using the above code you recommended solves that problem too.